# How don I find all solutions to $\sec(3 \theta)=1$ with $\theta$ in degrees?

Tags: trigonometry

Sorry. I don't have the Greek theta symbol in my device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sec(3 \theta) = 1 &\iff \frac{1}{\cos(3 \theta)} = 1 \\
&\iff 1 = \cos(3 \theta)\\
&\iff 3 \theta = 2 \pi n \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
&\iff \theta = \frac{2 \pi n}{3} \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}

These values are in radians. To convert them to degrees multiply by $\frac{180}{\pi}$.

Comment: Ok I think I understand, but you are using radians

Comment: What I got when. I attempted was 120 degrees + 120degreesK

Comment: Ok so I was correct, but do we exclude 0 in the solutions?

Comment: @Thetasquared No, $\theta = 0$ is a solution (in radians and in degrees).